# Windows Vista - dialog box hangs

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I am using Vista 32 bit.
Now after using for few hours, suddenly all apps stop opening dialog boxes.
For example, if I click "Save As" in notepad, the "Save" dialog box never shows up.
Even in Start menu, the apps stops opening.
But the total OS is not hanged, as I can switch between opened apps.

But no menus open!

I have AVG Free installed, UAC off.

Comment: When it appears as though the application has hung, does pressing ESC do anything?  Does it bring the application back to life again?

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem to this before and it turned out to be related to ISO mounting software. So if you have any ISO mounting software installed, like magicISO, Alcohol, Daemon Tools etc, you may want to remove it to test and make sure its up to the latest version.

Comment: i'm having a similar problem, and your pointing to CD/DVD software could be my cause as well.